# Connect jquery dataTables (with CRUD functions) to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

I'm beginer to web development and I find on net something really usefull  jquery datatables but now I have a problem becouse I know just javascript and jquery, so I have a problem How to connect datatable to mysql and how to send request and recieve response from server.

Here is the demo: https://editor.datatables.net/release/DataTables/extras/Editor/examples/bootstrap.html

So how I can connect this code example with my mysql dataBase?

Is there any tutorial step by step or something like that?

I need to do request and response ... I see in example file dataTables.php but this file is not in documentation...

Comment: I need some example with basic CRUD function and how to connect dataTable with mysql database...

Comment: did you look at this? http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: no, i want to my example connect to mysql database

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using ajax.

You can request the items using datatables and fill the table with a json response.

Here's an example

```
                  $('#yourTable').dataTable(
                    {

                        "bDestroy" : true,
                        "iDisplayLength" : 20,
                        "sAjaxDataProp" : "",
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "sAjaxSource" : "foo.php (Json to fill the table)"
                        "aoColumns" : [ {
                            "mData" : "person.age"
                        }, {
                            "mData" : "person.name"
                        }, 
                           {
                            "mData" : "person.id",
                        }, 
                           {
                            "mData" : "time",
                        }]
                    });
```

mData are basically your table columns, and datatables will fill each of those mData colums with the json you designated.

You can read documentation on how **mData** works here:

http://datatables.net/usage/columns  > Scroll to mData

Here is an example on how to get the mysql data from php for datatables.

http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

For a basic implementation you just need the **queries**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes but I want to get data from mysql database and not to send request on every search... just to send request on read, add, delete ... o this example on every search I send request... this is not really usefull

Comment: ok, I just want to catch full table and do the basic CRUD (create , read, update, delete) functions

Comment: Alright, you basically want to be able to do all the basic CRUD functions from the datatable?

Comment: yes, just crud function and search function to not call database

Comment: I try to use this plugin: https://editor.datatables.net/purchase/ but this plugin cost 70 euros ... so I dont want to pay them for basic crud functions...

Comment: By following the example in my response, you would fill the table with the json data and it wont do any request if you search, it will go through the json you received. For the rest of the crud operations you could assing an item id on each item and by clicking them you send a request to the server to delete that id.